# uncaught exception when using NSOperation:performSelector:

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, unrecognized-selector

I was trying to add a selector for my NSOperation but it gives me:

```
-[NSOperation sample]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e35830
2014-11-06 20:03:26.542 ****[1473:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSOperation sample]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e35830'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x303d8f53 0x3aa416af 0x303dc8e7 0x303db1d3 0x3032a598 0x820d5 0xa457d 0x590b9 0x3af24d7b 0x3af24d67 0x3af2b7c1 0x303a3821 0x303a20f5 0x3030cce7 0x3030cacb 0x34fda283 0x32baea41 0x78339 0x3af49ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code:

```
NSOperation *op = [[NSOperation alloc] init];
[op performSelector:@selector(sample)];
[MyQueue addOperation:op];

- (void)sample{
  NSLog(@"sample");
}
```

Comment: you want to call the `–sample` on an instance of the `NSOperation`, but it seems that method belongs to another objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error says, the `NSOperation` does not have a method called `sample`. You can call it here by either `[self sample];` or `[self performSelector:@selector(sample)];`

Comment: BTW that code is inside a viewcontroller, so if you mean self its the view controller. or maybe I dont get what you mean.

Comment: Yes, in that case `self` is the `UIViewController`. Since that `sample` method belongs to your `ViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I just used NSInvocationOperation a subclass of NSOperation which I think better of invoking a selector on a specified object.

Apple:

```
The NSInvocationOperation class is a concrete subclass of NSOperation that manages the 
execution of a single encapsulated task specified as an invocation.You can use this 
class to initiate an operation that consists of invoking a selector on 
a specified object. This class implements a non-concurrent operation.
```

Sample Code:

```
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sample) object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue=[NSOperationQueue new];

    NSInvocationOperation *operation=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeText) object:nil];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}

-(void)changeText{
    ........
    ..........
    ...........
}
```